# Fedora 27 update broke dual monitor setup

Tags: fedora, multi-monitor

Upgraded from Fedora 26 to 27 went smooth BUT after the first update my dual monitor setup is broken. It does not seem to pick up the extra monitor at all.

Using HDMI and if I run xrandr in only see the main monitor on the laptop:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1366×768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
1366×768 59.80*+
```

The output of `xrandr` is:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1366x768      59.80*+
[petrus@localhost amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261]$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / R7 M520] (rev 83)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

If I use `udevadm monitor` and plug the screen out and back in there is now output.

I saw that one of the updates was to fix a monitor issue, but mine was working before that, and not after.

I do I get back the use of my second monitor? I've googled around a a lot for this.

Comment: Any update on this issue? I'm having the same problem

Comment: No update. It fixed itself over night but I suspect it won't stay fixed because I didn't change anything.

Comment: Ah that is strange. I'm waiting on a replacement monitor cable to arrive to see if that fixes anything.

Answer (score 2):

Have you disabled switchable graphics in your bios? This worked for me I fought with this for a while and I did a bios update to be safe then I noticed that switchable graphics was on and I disabled the s3 sleep state in bios. I am not sure if the s3 sleep disabling fixed anything but I am pretty sure that the switchable graphics is what was causing my problem.

Comment: Next time this happens, I will try that to be sure that it fixed the issue and post here.